# How do I fix $GOPATH/go.mod exists but should not - Linux Fedora

Tags: linux, go, fedora

I am new to Golang, I am following this tutorial https://golang.org/doc/tutorial/getting-started but for some reason I keep getting this message every time I try to run the code:

`$GOPATH/go.mod exists but should not`

I have tried to look at answers like this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62062562/9785222 but I dont understand what is GOPATH and where is it.

I am using Vi as an editor on Linux Fedora

Comment: When I run ```go env``` I get the same message

Comment: What version of `go` are you using (`go version`)? What is the value of your `$GOPATH` environment variable (`echo $GOPATH`)?

Comment: Go Version: go1.16.5 linux/amd64

Comment: When I ```echo $GOPATH``` nothing but a blank line shows. I didn't add ```$GOPATH``` to my environment and I installed compiled binaries for linux as per instruction on the Golang Docs

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[GOPATH](https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/go#hdr-GOPATH_environment_variable) defaults to $HOME/go on Unix.

Remove the file $HOME/go/go.mod or explicitly set $GOPATH to a different directory.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I accidentally ```cd``` to $HOME/go and started writing and and running my code there.

Comment: `export GOPATH=/usr/local/go/bin` @ MacOS arm

Answer (score 3):

`$GOPATH` should point out to the `src` directory, in my case in Debian, I set `$GOPATH` to `/usr/local/go/src` and the problem was solved.

```
export $GOPATH=/usr/local/go/src
```

**What is GOPATH ?**

GOPATH is a variable that defines a folder, under which `GO` expects our code to reside . For more details, you can check [this link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-the-gopath)

Answer (score 1):

For me this was when trying to build in a docker container. It was solved by using a different build directory to the default.

E.g.:

```
FROM golang:1.21 AS gobuild

WORKDIR /build
```